# Automatic texbox height for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, resize, height

Background: 
I'm making a facebook wall-alike page, which will have many posts and you should be able to comment every post. And these textboxes, where you post type your comment in, should resize as in Facebook.

I have this code so far. It works but only in the FIRST textbox on the page, I would like it to work on every of them :)

Any chances to get it working for every textbox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
observe = function (element, event, handler) {
    element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
};
}
else {
observe = function (element, event, handler) {
    element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
};
}
function init () {
var text = document.getElementById('text');
function resize () {
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
/* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
function delayedResize () {
    window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
}
observe(text, 'change',  resize);
observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

text.focus();
text.select();
resize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide sample code of a live page? As it stands, the javascript you've shown here only works on the single element identified with the ID of text; therefore, no matter how many textareas you have, the only element affected will one of the elements on the page with that ID -- of which you should have only one, of course.

Approaching the code as it stands now, you need to change from `document.getElementById` to something like `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` then loop over the result. Try the following:

```
function init () {
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
...
var textareasLength = textareas.length;
for (var i = 0; i < textareasLength; i++) {
    observe(textareas[i], 'change',  resize);
    observe(textareas[i], 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(textareas[i], 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(textareas[i], 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(textareas[i], 'keydown', delayedResize);
}    
}
```

**EDIT:**

On review, among other things, your resize() function was only working on `text` variable as defined in the line immediately prior. Without totally refactoring your code, one way to get the functionality you want is the following:

```
function init () {
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
function resize() {
    if( arguments.length>0 ) {
      self=arguments[0];
    } else self=this;      
    self.style.height = 'auto';
    self.style.height = self.scrollHeight+'px';
}
/* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
function delayedResize() {
    var self=this;
    window.setTimeout(resize(self), 0);
}
var textareasLength = textareas.length;
for (var i = 0; i < textareasLength; i++) {
observe(textareas[i], 'change',  resize);
observe(textareas[i], 'cut',     delayedResize);
observe(textareas[i], 'paste',   delayedResize);
observe(textareas[i], 'drop',    delayedResize);
observe(textareas[i], 'keydown', delayedResize);
}    
}
```

This isn't optimal, but it should work.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QHsSn7MH

There is only one form, but they are being just looped through. Every form has the same ID. Only the hiddenid (the parent post id) is different.

Comment: Your pastebin shows only a single form with a single textarea. Is there any way you can display HTML with more than one so we can get a sense for it in context?

Comment: Sure, if you can be patient, I'll upload it to my server :) Just give me 2 minutes.

Comment: The comment textareas are inside "wallcomment" -divs

Answer (score 0):

It works only on one textbox because you're selecting only one with `document.getElementById('text')`. Remember that `id` attribute has to be unique.

You could do something like this:

```
texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
texts.forEach(function (text) {
    ... your current code for text ...
});
```

Where .text means you're selecting all elements with `class="text"`.